# How can I set up Visual Studio on my Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

My team uses .Net and I need to work them though I would like to do it from my Mac. Is VS Code useful or should I use online Visual Studio? What's the best way to work with fellow .Net developers on my Mac.

Comment: I don't believe you have a native version of visual studio for Mac.you need VM.That said this question is off topic

Comment: I don't see how the question led to a claim of native VS on Mac. I know there isn't. Your more useful part of the comment is the suggestion on using VM - can you expand more on that?

Answer (score 1):

Before Microsoft ships a full VS in OS X, you will have to run a desktop virtualization stack such as VMware Fusion to run Windows VM there or use Bootcamp to dual boot.

Visual Studio Code or Xamarin Studio might help in a few cases, but none of them claims to replace VS.

Comment: thanks lex, do you have experience with either? Which one would you recommend? I'm very new to this so would really appreciate any pointers..

Comment: @Roy I recommend Windows VM approach.